# How many video formats would I need? - Web

Tags: http, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

**I'm wondering how many different formats for each video would I need in order to support all major devices?**

Among the major devices I'm thinking: **Android phones + iPhone + iPad**.

Is it also good practice to encode videos with different bitrates?

---

There is too much conflicting info out there, and I am really confused.

Any ideas? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general purposes (common web browsers with flash) encode video to in H.264 with high profile. Mux with audio into flv or mp4 container. Use JW media player to play. Resolution and bitrate is almost unlimited for this clients.

For iPhone 2G/3G encode video into H.264 base profile in 320x200. Mux into mp4.
For iPhone 3GS/4/iPad encode video into H.264 high profile in 480x320. Mux into mp4.

For other purposes use new standard - WebM.